# How can I add admob ads to my game with one activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, ads

I made an android game following [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/create-an-android-game-from-scratch-or-port-your-existing-game.html) tutorial and I want to add admob ads before I upload it to the Google Play Store. I tried using [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/eclipse) guide, but I am confused because my app doesn't use a layout.xml and only has one activity. Is it possible to run ads in certain sections of my app without switching activities? If not, how hard is it to convert my app into one that uses multiple activities? I can provide any additional information, if necessary.

Here is my activity (I have a subclass with a few changes):

```html
package com.kilobolt.framework.implementation;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Audio;
import com.kilobolt.framework.FileIO;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Game;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Graphics;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Input;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Screen;

public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 480: 800;
        int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 800: 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);
        
        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getInitScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);
        
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyGame");
               
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         wakeLock.acquire();
        screen.resume();
        renderView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();
        renderView.pause();
        screen.pause();

        if (isFinishing())
            screen.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        return graphics;
    }

    @Override
    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }
    
    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {

     return screen;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, first of all sir, you have two options interstitial and adview, so which are you referring to? and please post a significant portion of your activity in which you would like to place the adview, so ppl can help you

Comment: Thank you, I added my activity to my post!

Comment: sir, check this [post](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial).. If you like to use layouts, then you will Use `AdView`, the answer below elaborates on that, but you do not want to use layouts then you can use `Interstitial` please check that **post** it elaborates on the **Interstitial Add** and how to put it in your app. try it, if that post solves your requirement please delete the question, based on stackoverflow standards its a poor question because of lack of research..

Answer (score 1):

It possible to add ads without xml. See this [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html). The piece of code below is from the document.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// Create a banner ad. The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before calling loadAd.
mAdView = new AdView(this);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

// Create an ad request.
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

// Optionally populate the ad request builder.
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.
layout.addView(mAdView);

// Start loading the ad.
mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a way to do it without using layouts?  When I create a layout, all I see is a blank screen and my ad.

Comment: adjust layout accordingly using `setLayoutParams`. I edited the answer. You can change the value of LinearLayout.Params to set the layout on the screen.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial for layout setting [Link](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html)

Comment: If you don't want to use layouts, check on the comment by @ Elltz. Use `Interstitial`